# Two cases of inverse image of conjugacy class of quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $K \vartriangleleft G$ is a normal subgroup of order $2$,  $\bar{G} =
>  G/K$. Let $\bar{C}$ be a conjugacy class in $\bar{G}$, $S$ be the
>    inverse image of $\bar{C}$ in $G$, then one of the following two cases
>    occurs.
>
> (a) $S = C$ is a single conjugacy class and $|C| = 2|\bar{C}|$.
>
> (b) $S = C_1 \cup C_2$ is made up of two conjugacy classes and $|C_1|
>  = |C_2| = |C|$.

Having difficulty proving this assertion. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $|S|=2|\bar C|$ because the order of $K$ is $2$.

Writing $K=\{1, k\}$, note that $k^{-1}=k$, and it is in the center of $G$. 
Let $x\in S$ be arbitrary, and set $y=xk$, the other preimage of $xK$ under $f:G\to G/K$.

Let $C_1:=\{gxg^{-1}:g\in G\}$ and $C_2:=\{gyg^{-1}:g\in G\}$. 
Observe that $f(C_i)=\bar C$ for both $i=1,2$.

Show that $S=C_1\cup C_2$, and that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are either disjoint or equal, according to whether $y$ is a conjugate of $x$ or not.